# How to fetch data from mysql in android?

Tags: android, json, android-json

Hello i am new in android , I followed some online tutorial to fetch data from mysql in android.But when ever i am trying to fetch data i am getting json Exception of "No Value for : json Data".

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String myJSON;

    private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "message_recd";
    private static final String TAG_ADD ="message_sent";

    JSONArray peoples = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;

    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        getData();
    }


    protected void showList(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
                for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
                String name=null, address=null;

                if(c.has("message_recd"))
                    name = c.getString("message_recd");
                else if(c.has("message_sent"))
                    address = c.getString("message_sent");

                HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();


                persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
                persons.put(TAG_ADD,address);
                personList.add(persons);
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[]{TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                    new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.address}
            );

            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+myJSON+"]");
        }
    }

    public void getData(){
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/progress_card/messages/get_messages1.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;
                showList();
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
    10-01 03:07:55.910: I/tagconvertstr(1953): [{"0":{"message_recd":"hello is it working really?"},"1":{"message_recd":"hello"},"2":{"message_recd":"checking"},"3":{"message_recd":"qwerty"},"4":{"message_recd":"qweqwdqdqd"},"5":{"message_recd":"ojhdsgwkjsbawdfvkjn"},"6":{"message_recd":"qwertyyt"},"7":{"message_recd":"qwertyytqwertyytqwertyytqwertyytqwertyytqwertyyt"},"8":{"message_sent":"hey whtas up"},"9":{"message_sent":"hey whtas up again"},"10":{"message_sent":"hey whtas up hey whtas up hey whtas up hey whtas up hey whtas up "}}
10-01 03:07:55.910: I/tagconvertstr(1953): ]
```

Json Response:

```
{"0":{"message_recd":"hello is it working really?"},"1":{"message_recd":"hello"},"2":{"message_recd":"checking"},"3":{"message_recd":"qwerty"},"4":{"message_recd":"qweqwdqdqd"},"5":{"message_recd":"ojhdsgwkjsbawdfvkjn"},"6":{"message_recd":"qwertyyt"},"7":{"message_sent":"hey whtas up"},"8":{"message_sent":"hey whtas up again"}}
```

Comment: To access MySQL database through Android, the best way to do it is to use PHP to access the database. Next, you will be able, with PHP to generate JSON strings from results of your queries.

Comment: post the whole json response you are getting from the server

Comment: try to extract JSON value in " void onPostExecute(String result){} "    method of  AsyncTask..

Answer (score 0):

See this is what you are trying to do :- 
In post execute you do :-   `myJSON=result;`

Now myJson's json structure is :-  `{"0":{"message_recd":"hello is it working really?"},"1":{"message_recd":"hello"},"2":{"message_recd":"checking"},"3":{"message_recd":"qwerty"},"4":{"message_recd":"qweqwdqdqd"},"5":{"message_recd":"ojhdsgwkjsbawdfvkjn"},"6":{"message_recd":"qwertyyt"},"7":{"message_sent":"hey whtas up"},"8":{"message_sent":"hey whtas up again"}}`

In Json {} means a Json Object and [] means its Json Array..Now in method showList() you do :-

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
```

where TAG_RESULTS = "result"

So i ask Json Object jsonObj to give me a Json Array whose key is "result" but there is none, see the Json structure. In fact there is no array on that Json Object, it has multiple Json Objects with keys 0,1,2,3...8.

So to get all the Json objects from jsonObj we will loop like this :-

```
for(int i=0;i < jsonObj.length;i++) {

JsonObject myJsonObject = jsonObj.getJsonObject(i);

//check if it has value for key and do something with value
if(myJsonObject.has("message_recd")) {

  String meesageRecieved = myJsonObject.getString("message_recd")

//Add it to the hash map
}

// do same if we have more keys like message_recd in json 
}
```

The Json structure you are getting from that url is not what you think you are getting, it has no result array.. Happy android coding :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining in brief,but still i am not getting json data

Comment: Rishabh's code would work perfectly once our JSON structure is changed to [{"message_sent":"Hey There"},{"message_recd:"Cool!!"}]. No need of having those 0,1,2,etc.

Comment: @DhirenKumawat hi dhiren..in method showList remove line peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);  and change this 
                for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++) to for(int i=0;i<jsonObj.length();i++) then run it..

Answer (score 0):

You are getting response is not in json structure. Its look gook in

### Advance Rest Client

```
{"0":{"message_recd":"hello is it working really?"},"1":{"message_recd":"hello"},"2":{"message_recd":"checking"},"3":{"message_recd":"qwerty"},"4":{"message_recd":"qweqwdqdqd"},"5":{"message_recd":"ojhdsgwkjsbawdfvkjn"},"6":{"message_recd":"qwertyyt"},"7":{"message_sent":"hey whtas up"},"8":{"message_sent":"hey whtas up again"}}
```

but in android json should look like :

```
{"response":"success","data":[{"cityid":"5","citynm":"Hyderabad"}]}
```